# PHP SDK Facebook API 2.5 - post on fanpage - how to

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.5

I've got problems with posting from PHP on Facebook PAGE wall. 
Same code posts for my personal account (admin on that Facebook page) - but without success when i trying to post on Page.

**code working to post on user wall**
         $linkData = [
        'link' => 'http://www.somewebpagelink.com',
        'message' => 'User provided message',
        'description' => 'test',
        'caption' => 'caption',
        'published' => 'true'
        ];

```
    try {
      // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
      $response = $fb->post('me/feed', $linkData, $accessToken);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

    echo 'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id'];
```

But when i've change

```
$response = $fb->post('https://graph.facebook.com/{valid_page_id}/feed', $linkData, $accessToken);
```

Where valid_page_id is my real page id, it doesn't post on Facebook page.

Can someone help ?

Ps. Defined app is public, user i've used as login had admin privileges to this page.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use a page access token to post on the page as the page

Comment: @WizKid - I've get it using this:

    `$response = $fb->get('/me/accounts');`
    `$json = json_decode($response->getBody(),true);`
    `$page_token = $json['data']['0']['access_token'];`

Where [0] is the page i've want to post.

`$response = $fb->post('http://graph.facebook.com/{my_page_id}/feed', $linkData, $page_token);`

Without success :-(

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. It's easy. If someone need it:

```
$response = $fb->post('{page_id}/feed', $linkData, $page_token);
```

This is only thing i must to do, to post on Facebook page :-)